# Wedge Product of One-Form and Two-Form Reducing to Zero

Tags: differential-forms

$w^{a}_{\;a} \wedge e^a = 0$

Where $w^{a}_{\;a}$ is a two-form, and $e^a$ is a one-form. 
Why does their wedge equal zero?
Is it because $w^{a}_{\;a} = 0$ on its own?

Comment: The two form doesn't necessarily equal zero. In particular it could equal $\theta \wedge e^a$, where $\theta$ is some nonzero oneform.

Comment: To add onto Spencer's answer, recall that any one form wedge with itself is 0 because of the symmetric definition of wedge product for one forms.